# What is the encoding of Java byte type?

Tags: java, encoding, byte

when I do the following code :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Hello John";
        System.out.println(str.getBytes());
    }
}
```

What is the encoding type for str.getBytes(). is it ASCII UTF or what ?

Comment: Just read the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes--)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bytes don't have an encoding. They're bytes.

See the Javadoc of [`String.getBytes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes--):

> Encodes this String into a sequence of bytes using the platform's default charset

So, it's whatever your default charset is. You can find out what that is at runtime using [`Charset.defaultCharset()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset--).

If you want the bytes in a particular charset, specify it, e.g.:

```
str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
// or
str.getBytes(Charset.forName("the name of the desired charset"))
```

(And note that `System.out.println(str.getBytes());` won't print anything related to the contents of the array).

Comment: So let's say I have a machine that support specific encoding other than ASCII or UTF and I want to communicate with a Java app, how do I define encoding type for that machine ? Can I just say byte or be more specific ?

Comment: @user14696236 *"encoding other than ..."* Like what? We can't adequately answer a wide open question like that, but if you tell us what encoding you're talking about, we might be able to give you an exact answer.

Comment: something like EBCDIC

Comment: @user14696236 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html